# Accessor function for pointer data field

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an accessor function for a data field in the "Team" class I have created. Each team member has a pointer data field to another team member, called "partner." With the getter, I want to return the address of the team member's partner.

The data field Partner is defined as:

```
Team *partner;
```

I defined the function as follows in the header:

```
Team getPartner();
```

Here is the accessor function I have tried so far:

```
Team Team::getPartner()
{
    return *partner;
}
```

And here is the syntax I'm trying to use in the main function (each team member was created as pointers; Harry is the name of one of the objects for whom a partner has been set)

```
cout << Harry->getPartner() << endl;
```

This accessor function for the pointer to another object is the only part of my code that isn't working. Unfortunately, I don't understand the error messages my compiler is giving me. I'd greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Team')

Comment: What would you expect to be printed by the last statement? You say: "With the getter, I want to return the address of the team member's partner." This implies you actually want to return `Team*` from `getPartner()`.

Comment: Have you overloaded `ostream& operator<<` for `Team`?

Comment: No, how would I overload it?

Comment: I want to return the address, I guess. I'm able to do this in the main function if I dereference, i.e. if I write Harry->partner, but I'm not able to figure out how to do this with a getter.

Comment: `Team* Team::getPartner()
{
    return partner;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the address of the partner, then say so in your function return type

```
Team* getPartner();
```

...

```
Team* Team::getPartner()
{
    return partner;
}
```

Alternatively, you could return a reference to the partner

```
Team& Team::GetPartner()
{
     return *partner;
}
```

But in order to

```
cout << Harry->GetPartner();
```

You'd have to tell the compiler how do you want it to understand << for Teams.

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& o, const Team& team)  
{ 
    return o << team.name << team.somethingelse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I just had trouble working out exactly where to place pointers, etc. Thanks again.